# Django model relationships

Tags: django, model

I have 3 Django model classes: 
1. Customer - contains multiple billing and shipping addresses
2. Address - can be billing or shipping address
3. Order - contain reference to 1 customer, 1 billing address and 1 shipping addresses chosen by the customer.

How do I create an Order class that would render in the admin page so that users can choose which shipping address to use?

The Address class has a property called name so that the user can assign short names like "HQ" or "NY Branch". I want users to be able to select the shipping address from a drop-down list using the short names. I'm a slow noob.

**UPDATE**

**CODE**
Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)        
    shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=80)// Should be a drop list based on the customer above
    ...
```

Customer model:

```
class Customer(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)    
    username = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Address model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, help_text='Easy to remember name like "HQ"')    
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    address_type = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=ADDRESS_TYPES,)
    street_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield):

> The `__unicode__` method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field's choices...

So, [override `Address.__unicode__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__).

Comment: Theoretically, I want to do something like this in my Order class:
`address = models.OneToManyField(customer.Address.all()). Any ideas?

Comment: No, you don't want to do that. You want a many-to-many relation, otherwise you can't use an address in multiple orders.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this questions:

[How to work with dynamic data in Admin Panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749318/django-administration-qustions-how-too-work-with-dynamic-data-in-admin-panel)

[django ForeignKey model filter in admin-area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822985/django-foreignkey-model-filter-in-admin-area/6823372#6823372)

I think they are quite similar to your question. All you need is to set choices in admin.py from Address model.

Comment: Your suggestion might be the solution for the problem. However, I'm having problems because the Order object does not have a direct relationship with the Address object. I need the form to display only address names from the customer object referenced by the customer field in the Order class.

Comment: If you want to do such thing with standart Django tools, you must change fields to ManyToMany/ForeignKey. If you want to use drop-down autoselect menu - look at django-ajax-select. There will be the way to custom info in this drop down menu... And this is only autoselect widget, which worked for me.